How to prevent borrowing *self multiple times?
I wrote a random card game for practice and got a multiple borrow error.
struct Card {
    val: i32,
}

struct Game {
    card1: Card,
    card2: Card,
    idx: usize,
}

impl Game {
    fn draw(&mut self) -> &mut Card {
        match self.idx {
            0 => {
                self.idx = 1;
                &mut self.card1
            }
            1 => {
                self.idx = 0;
                &mut self.card2
            }
            _ => &mut self.card1,
        }
    }
    fn do_something(&mut self, card1: &mut Card, card2: &mut Card) {
        card1.val += 1;
        card2.val += 2;
    }
    fn run(&mut self) {
        let card1 = self.draw();
        let card2 = self.draw();
        self.do_something(card1, card2);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut game = Game {
        card1: Card { val: 1 },
        card2: Card { val: 2 },
        idx: 0,
    };
    game.run();
}

There are two structs: Card and Game.
Card struct simply holds a value.
Game struct contains two cards and an index.
There are three methods in Game:

draw - it draw a card from two according to index.
do_something - it do some magical things to two cards.
run - it runs the above two functions.

The error happens in the third function:
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:31:21
   |
30 |         let card1 = self.draw();
   |                     ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
31 |         let card2 = self.draw();
   |                     ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
32 |         self.do_something(card1, card2);
   |                           ----- first borrow later used here

This link can quickly show the error, playground.
Can you help me make some adjustments to correct the codes and keep the functionality of the three functions? Thanks!
I want to maintain all references here to avoid copying cards.

I don't think there is any way you can make these signatures work with Rust's borrowing model. In particular, if you call self.draw() three times then you have two mutable aliases to the same value, something expressly forbidden in Rust. draw() in particular is extremely problematic; I don't think you can "keep the functionality" of this function because it runs very strongly against the grain of how Rust is intended to be used.

Even do_something() suffers the same problem. card1 and card2 both will alias self unless you are passing in cards not owned by self so this signature simply cannot work in Rust, period.

You don't appear to need a mutable borrow of self in do_something: fn do_something (&self, ...

@MadPhysicist It doesn't matter because the mutable borrows still alias self improperly. self isn't actually needed at all; removing it completely could potentially work.

Add fn draw_twice(&mut self) -> (&mut Card, &mut Card) and use that.

Also, what if you had a Game { idx: 2, /* ... */ }? This is not an error condition, and would make draw actually perform exclusive borrow of card1 twice.

You can't have references to parts of a struct and still interact with a struct normally. Mutable references completely prevent any reading or writing to a data structure.
For example you couldn't draw a card if a reference to an already drawn card exists anywhere. RefCell/Mutex allows bypassing this but it's not necessary for your situation.
Instead, consider returning an index that uniquely refers to a certain card:
struct Card {
    val: i32,
}

struct Game {
    cards: [Card; 2],
    idx: usize,
}

// Create a new type to ensure only card indexes are allowed by the type checker to refer to cards.
// Internally it's just an int
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct CardIndex(usize);

impl Game {
    fn draw(&mut self) -> CardIndex {
        self.idx += 1;
        return CardIndex((self.idx + self.cards.len() - 1)%self.cards.len())
    }
    fn do_something(&mut self, card1: CardIndex, card2: CardIndex) {
        self.cards[card1.0].val += 1;
        self.cards[card2.0].val += 2;
    }
    fn run(&mut self) {
        let card1 = self.draw();
        let card2 = self.draw();
        self.do_something(card1, card2);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut game = Game {
        cards: [
            Card { val: 1 },
            Card { val: 2 }
        ],
        idx: 0,
    };
    game.run();
}


Seeing as the only item in the Card struct is a val with type i32(which implements the Copy trait), why not implement the Copy trait for the Card struct itself? So that it would look like so:
struct Card {
    val: i32,
}

struct Game {
    card1: Card,
    card2: Card,
    idx: usize,
}

impl Game {
    
    fn draw(&mut self) -> Card {
        match self.idx {
            0 => {
                self.idx = 1;
                self.card1
            }
            1 => {
                self.idx = 0;
                self.card2
            }
            _ => self.card1,
        }
    }
    
    fn do_something(&self, card1: &mut Card, card2: &mut Card) {
        card1.val += 1;
        card2.val += 2;
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        let mut card1 = self.draw();
        let mut card2 = self.draw();
        println!("before do_something, card1: {}, card2: {}", card1.val, card2.val);
        self.do_something(&mut card1, &mut card2);
        println!("after do_something, card1: {}, card2: {}", card1.val, card2.val);
    }
}


If card1 and card2 are copied into do_something, "card1.val += 1" and "card2.val += 2" will not affect the original card1 and card2 in run. They only change the duplicated values.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fe4f4fa5a8c0ff3c330684392429e9f7

@Leo Answer has been modified, does it work for you ?
